# XPath query that matches multiple attributes of any particular element name

Tags: xpath

Given the following sample XML:

```
<a z="123" y="321"></a>
<b z="456" y="654"></b>

<c x="456" w="654"></c>
<c x="123" w="111"></c>
<c x="789" w="321"></c>
```

I need an xpath query that will return element 'a', because there is a 'c' element whose @x equals the a's @z, and whose @w does NOT equal the a's @y.

Notice that 'b' is not returned because there is a 'c' element where @x=@z and @w=@y.

Also, the elements being returned can be any element (*). The important bit is there is a matching 'c' element, where the second attribute doesn't match.

The closest I've come up with is this:

```
//*[@z=//c/@x and .[@y != //c/@w]]
```

However in my sample above, this would not return 'a' because @z matches @x of a 'c' element, and @y matches @w of a **different** 'c' element. The second attribute check needs to be made against the same 'c' element.

I hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

This XPath 2.0 expression:

```
//*[
    let $a := . 
    return 
     following-sibling::*[@x eq $a/@z and not(@w eq $a/@y)] 
    ]
```

Will bind the matched element to a variable in a predicate, and then use it in a predicate for the following-sibling elements of that context element to see if their attributes satisfy the stated requirements.

Comment: Nice (+1), but in place of `follow-sibling::*`, use `../*` to avoid order dependency among siblings, or `//*` for existence checking anywhere in document.  Also, might want to note that this selection is not possible in XPath 1.0 without the use of constructs from the calling language.

Comment: Unfortunately it looks like the program I'm using doesn't support this, I suspect it only supports XPath 1.0. It's complaining at the first $ saying "only predicate starts, axes, whitespace, conjunctions and operators are permitted after node names". Sounds like it thinks 'let' is a node name rather than a variable declaration.